# Через что лучше создавать тест на сайте?

Tags: php, javascript

Всем привет!

Собираюсь впервые сделать тест на своем сайте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, через что лучше это делать: JavaScript или PHP? В интернете однозначного ответа или рекомендации не нашёл.
В чем разница реализаций, какой вариант проще, какой удобнее для конечного пользователя?

Тест небольшой, на 15 вопросов (то есть обработка колоссального количества данных не планируется).

Comment: Это зависит от многих параметров. Лучше начните создавать хоть как-нибудь, чтобы понять что у вас где будет храниться и как выводиться.

Answer (score 2):

Важно понимать, что логика JS будет выполняться в браузере клиента, то есть вы отдадите ему ваш JS скрипт через вебсеврер, а он сам его выполнит. Это удобно и гибко в некоторых случаях. 
Код PHP скрипта вы никогда не отдадите клиенту, он всегда выполниться у вас на сервере и клиенту получит только сгенерированную страницу без какой либо логики. Я считаю метод генерации страниц на сервере с помощью php более подходящим для генерации контента на странице, а js следует использовать для добавления удобств на страницу, будь то раскрывающиеся меню и динамический контент.

Как начать в JS - https://learn.javascript.ru/

Как начать с PHP - http://php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.php

Comment: Ну значит правильно, что я сделал через php. К примеру вот самое простое: 
<?php
   $yes = 0;
   $not = 0;
      if ($_POST[q1] == a){$yes++;} else {$not++;}
      if ($_POST[q2] == a){$yes++;} else {$not++;}
?>
Ну и далее буду его изменять.